# in R convert multhist to multiple lines (but not for density)

Tags: r, graph, histogram, plotrix

I have a data structure with 21 lists of numeric values which I wish to create a histo-graph for, but instead of bars I would like lines instead as it is easier to visualise for 21 series of data on one graph, and also without being a density, i.e I want the Y axis to still be frequency.

I have this R code below, but using type="l" or lines() does not seem to work

> multhist(first_eigv,main="Amino Acid Residue Frequencies of First 
>   Eigenvector",breaks=11,ylab="Frequency",xlab="Eigenvalue",freq=TRUE,col=1:21)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You could improve your question. Please read [how to provide minimal reproducible examples in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610). Then edit & improve it accordingly. A good post usually provides minimal input data, the desired output data & code tries - all copy-paste-run'able in a new/clean R session. I.e. you could provide a toy data set, the required `library` calls etc

Comment: i.e like this one http://fms-itskills.ncl.ac.uk/office2003/dhss/histograms.html?style=   but with 21 series not just the two